# Im trying to delete duplicates in excel from two columns AND also delete the original too

Tags: excel

We have two email lists that have been "mixed" by mistake.

The first column has:

- email addresses that we want
- as well aso some we don't want there.

The second column has:

- the email addresses that aren't needed
- and that we want to extract from column 1.

Is there a simple way to delete the duplicates and also delete unwanted the email addresses from column 1 too?

I hope you can understand my ramble.

Answer (score 1):

For the duplicate part :

```
Go to the "data" Tab and click "remove duplicates", having selected the columns.
```

For the data you do not want, you might need "filters" if I understood well your problem.

```
Go to the "data" Tab, click "filters" and select data you want, delete the rows.
```

Comment: I can remove the duplicates easy enough but that still leaves the original email address still in the list. We need that removed too.

Comment: Then, add a new column "=count.if(A:A;A1) (assuming A is the column with email and you are on the first line). Filter the "2" and remove duplicates :-)